# UI will be blocked when show FancyAlert while closing Modal in ios using nativescript typescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing an ios and android mobile application using native script angular. I am using the TNSFancyalert plugin to show alert info, When I was close this TNSFancyAlert the dialog was closed but the plugin was affecting the main UI. Any issues with this plugin?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem, possibly with a screenshot, how it affects the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement like this:-

1. Install tns plugin add nativescript-fancyalert.
2. Import now:-

   import { TNSFancyAlert, TNSFancyAlertButton } from "nativescript-fancyalert";
3. Call alert:-

   // show success

   TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess(
   "Success!",
   "Fancy alerts are nice.",
   "Yes they are!"
   );
4. Other one like:-

   // show success

   TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess(
    "Success!",
    "Fancy alerts are nice.",
    "Yes they are!"
   ).then(() => {
    /* user pressed the button */
   });

Comment: Already I tried this all steps. Alert is working properly but when close the alert model UI will be blocked up to one minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh the UI after the TNSFancyAlert closes as a result of a "TNSFancyAlertButton" action, then you need to wrap the callback in the NgZone run method.

```
export FooComponent {

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    //       
  }

  openAlert() {

    TNSFancyAlert.showCustomButtons([
      new TNSFancyAlertButton({
        label: "Action label",
        action: () => {
          this.asyncJob().subscribe(() => {

            this.zone.run(() => {

              // do something that should reflect the UI

            })
          })       
        }
      })
    ])
  }
}
```